# How to add non-public website files on S3 based on website users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

On our website we want to add the possibility to upload personal files. These files should be non-public and can optionally be shared with other people on the website. I once built a similar functionality for another project in which I stored files in a MongoDB instance on the server. This allowed us to build fine grained accessibility rules for each file. For this project however, we want to store the files on Amazon S3. And now I'm wondering how I could build similar accessibility rules using S3.

I've stored files on S3 before, but those were only public files. Since these files are restricted to one specific user (or to the ones who the files was shared with) I'm not sure how I could do that using S3. I searched around the internet and I found some information on defining user policies. These policies are based on S3 users however, and not on my website users. So I can't really find a standard way of doing this (or maybe I'm searching for the wrong words).

Is there a way that I can require a specific secret for a file on S3, possibly in the url? Or are there other standard ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your happy with S3 for your content store, you could look at AWS CloudFront CDN and the API to provide access control. Cloud Front will happily use an S3 bucket as a private origin, and offers signed URLs to grant temporary access.

You can programatically generate a cloudfront URL from your code pointing to a resource in s3 and it will enforce a policy you provide. The url provides temporary access based on various criteria like `IpAddress` and `DateLessThan`. These can be used to dynamically construct a url restricted to a specific IP(ie the current users IP) and is only valid until a specific date/time.

Taken from the AWS docs:
[image: Typical s3 backed Cloudfront distribution]

`A signed URL includes additional information, for example, an expiration date and time, that gives you more control over access to your content. This additional information appears in a policy statement, which is based on either a canned policy or a custom policy.`

See AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: Thanks for your idea. That looks like a great service. It's still not totally secure though, since people working on the same ip address can still access the file while they didn't log into our server. Do you know of a way to provide a temporary secret to the file in the url, so that if you don't know the secret you cannot access it? (I'm handling medical data here, so I need to highest level of security)

Comment: I agree it has some gaps - but in the real world security is always a compromise and theres plenty is side benefits to serving content over a cdn. Given the generated url is only available to the intended client as handled by your existing app authentication. Then assuming the document containing the link is sent over https so only the intended client would have it. Then assume the link only works for a few seconds or whatevers appropriate. If you need more control maybe aws api gateway and lambda, or lambda edge. Boat load more work, but will give you more control. Im curious what else exists